# listview null values

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, null, label

I don't want the label to show if the field is null.  In my database rows, data isn't complete for all columns.

I thought this would work:

```
 <% if(# Eval("recipe_by") == null){%><br /><br /><%} else {%>Recipe by:
<br /><br /> <asp:Label ID="recipe_byLabel" Font-Bold="True" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("recipe_by") %>' /> }
```

I get this error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS1040:
>   Preprocessor directives must appear as
>   the first non-whitespace character on
>   a line
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 386: Line 387:          Line
>   388:<% if(# Eval("recipe_by") ==
>   null){%>
> <%} else {%>Recipe
>   by: Line 389:
>  ' /> } Line 390:
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS1040:
>   Preprocessor directives must appear as
>   the first non-whitespace character on
>   a line
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 386: Line 387:          Line
>   388:<% if(# Eval("recipe_by") ==
>   null){%>
> <%} else {%>Recipe
>   by: Line 389:
>  ' /> } Line 390:

Answer (score 1):

It's the hash character (#), as we call it in blighty - I'm pretty sure you don't want that there.  That's used for [Preprocessor Directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha%28VS.71%29.aspx).

Comment: The answer I posted from someone else actually didn't work, still shows the label when null.    I took out the first # charater and got this error

Compiler Error Message: CS1010: Newline in constant

Source Error:

 

Line 407:                        Serving size:<br /><br />
Line 408:                        <asp:Label ID="serving_sizeLabel"  Font-Bold="True"  runat="server" 
Line 409:                            Text='<%# Eval("serving_size") %>' />
Line 410:             
Line 411:

Answer (score 0):

Here it is

```
<span>  
 <%# (Eval("recipe_by")==null)? "<br/><br/>":"Recipe By:<br/><br/>" %></span>  
    <asp:Label ID="recipe_byLabel" Font-Bold="True" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("recipe_by") %>' />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'

Source Error:



Line 388:         
Line 389:
Line 390:<asp:Label ID="recipe_byLabel" Font-Bold="True" Text="Recipe by:" runat="server"  
Line 391: Visible='<%# (Convert.ToString(Eval("recipe_by")))? Boolean.Parse("false"):Boolean.Parse("true") %>'></asp:Label>  
Line 392:
```

I could've swore that would do it!

Answer (score 0):

If you get tired of trying to tweak the inline tags to work right, you could use two other approaches:

- code behind
- stored procedure / sql statement return

Code behind is my favorite  -- if you're operating on an object like a gridview, etc., you might have to use the onrowdatabound or other similar event to set visible properties.

If you *must* use inline tags, sometimes, maybe it would be easier just to have a "visible" column in your SQL Statement -- i.e.:

```
SELECT
   field1,
   field2,
   CASE WHEN recipe_by is null, 'false' ELSE 'true' END as recipe_by_visible
FROM
   table
```

And then in your inline code:

```
...
visible = <% eval("recipe_by_visible") %>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up using,,,  works GREAT!!

```
<span><%# (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(Eval("yield"))))? "":" <br/><br/>Yield:<br/><br/>" %></span>  
<asp:Label ID="yieldLabel" Font-Bold="True" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("yield") %>' />
```